# Accesing data from one mysql database to another in MYSQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, mysql-workbench

I have two different databases. I have to access data from one database and insert them into another ( with some data processing included, it is not only to copy data ) Also, the schema is really complex and each table has many rows, so copying data into schema in the second database is not an option. I have to do that using MySQL Workbench, so I have to do it using SQL queries. Is there a way to create a  connection from one database to another and access its data?

Comment: You need a programming language to migrate what ever data you have to your other database, or simply make a standardized values such as CVS, JSON, XML. In order to import all this Queries to your new db . Because Databases cannot talk to each other they need guidance in terms of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

While MySQL Workbench can be used to transfer data between servers (e.g. as part of a migration process) it is not useful when you have to process the data first. Instead you have 2 other options:

1. Use a dedicated tool you write yourself to do that (as eddwinpaz mentioned).
2. Use the capabilities of your server. That is, copy the data to the target server, into a temporary table (using dump and restore). Then use queries to modify the data as you need it. Finally copy it to the target table.